# Opening a popup in Javascript is showing same value rather than showing different values

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

```
<div>       
    <% items.forEach(function(itemname,index) { %>
               <table>
                <tr>
                   <td>
                     <a href="#Test"><img src="samplebutton.png"></a>  
                <div id="Test">
               <div>
                         <input type="text" value="<%= itemname %>">
                   </div>
            </div>
           </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
    <% }) %>
</div>
```

I have following code.In this code I have three 'sample button icon' on my page and three 'items' are passed in this ejs file. If I click on any 'sample button icon' then via href "Test" a input box popup will open where i can type a 'item name' and by default in that input box the passed 'item name' from ejs file should show. 
Now the problem coming is if I click on any sample button icon then only the first item name is getting displayed in input pop up. I want that, if i click on 1st sample button icon then by default first item name should be displayed and if i click on 2nd sample button icon then by default second item name should be displayed and so on. So, where I am doing mistake in this code? I tried to move the  out of the main div then also it is displaying only 1st item name.

Comment: post your JS or fiddle too

Comment: @YogeshMistry Is JS necessary because I checked the three items are getting passed in ejs file properly.  Infact if I write <%= itemname %> in <td> block then all 3 items name are getting printed in the page before sample button icon..

Comment: You are using the same id for all three items. If there are multiple ids with the same value first one will be considered.

Try appending index in the id

 <a href="#Test<%= index %>"><img src="samplebutton.png"></a>  
 <div id="Test<%= index %>">

Comment: @TalhaAwan Thanks alot working perfectly. One more question if I add a button inside div tag with id "Test" like <a href="https://www.google.co.in">Link</a> then this 'Link' button is not working. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>       
    <% items.forEach(function(itemname,index) { %>
               <table>
                <tr>
                   <td>
                     <a href="#Test<%= index %>"><img src="samplebutton.png"></a>  
                <div id="Test<%= index %>">
               <div>
                         <input type="text" value="<%= itemname %>">
                   </div>
            </div>
           </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
    <% }) %>
</div>
```